# Error when trying to iterate over fields in PyQGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

In my script I'm getting the following error message and I don't understand why:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'  Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/denni/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Flae2Halt\Flae2Halt.py",
>   line 313, in run
>       self.Channel2()   File "C:/Users/denni/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Flae2Halt\Flae2Halt.py",
>   line 284, in Channel2
>       for field in channel1.fields(): AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'

I have a vector layer and I'm trying to iterate over its fields. First I get the layer from this function:

```
def Channel1(self):
    channel = self.getChannel()
    param = {'INPUT': channel,
             'EXPRESSION':  "\"Zuordnung\" = 1 OR \"Zuordnung\" = 3",
             'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }
    channel1 = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', param)
    return channel1
```

This function should return a QgisVectorLayer right?
Next to the function with the iteration:

```
def Channel2(self):
    channel1 = self.Channel1()
    fieldname = self.dlg.Channel_ID.currentText()
    fieldNameList = []
    for field in channel1.fields():
        if not (field.name == fieldname):
            fieldNameList.append(field.name)
    param = {'INPUT': channel1,
             'COLUMN': fieldNameList,
             'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
    channel2 = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn', param)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(channel2)
    return channel2
```

According to the official developer [Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html) `for field in vlayer.fields()` is the function to iterate over the fields of a layer.

Apparently "channel1" is not a QgsVectorLayer object after all or fields() is not working anymore in QGIS3.

Ahhh! I must have done a stupid error somewhere but I just don't see it.

I'm using QGIS 3.4

Comment: `return channel1['OUTPUT']`

Comment: You should run your script in the QGIS script panel. And inspect step by step your variables. You would notice that `channel1` is not a QgsVectorLayer but a dictionary. @BERA is right

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a stupid error. BERA's answer works perfectly. Thank you.